# How to read XML file which includes another XML file using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, include, nokogiri

I have two XML Files

```
Parent.xml
<root>
  <data>data</data>
</root>
```

and

```
Child.xml
<Croot>
  <tag> include parentr data here </tag>
</Croot>
```

I want to include the data present in the parent.xml such a way that Nokogiri parser can read import it and read it. Can anyone help me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example:

https://gist.github.com/wrburgess/1481481

1. Open the doc
2. XPath to insertion point
3. Create new nodes at that location

Comment: Is it possible to put the code (and perhaps sample input and output) into the answer itself?  Links go bad over time...